# MS-DOS | Get user input without prompt

Tags: dos

I've got to create a batch file that takes user input that saves and displays it in a log.txt file. However the user/my teacher will input text such as:

'batch file name here'.bat "frank" f123

ive got to take the name and username that they type and display it like this:

frank

f123

i can get the name but above i get 'Echo is off'. Currently my code:

@echo off

name=

username=

if not exist "c:\User_records" md c:\User_records

@echo %name% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt

@echo %username% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt

@echo %date% %time% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set name=%~1
set username=%~2
if not exist "c:\User_records" md c:\User_records
@echo %name% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt
@echo %username% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt
@echo %date% %time% >>c:\User_records\Users.txt
echo %name%
echo %username%
```

Comment: Or remove the last two lines if you want an output to log file only.

Comment: nice one fella that'll do